# Page Load Timeout Length with Cache Manifest Fallback

Tags: asp.net, browser, timeout, fallback, cache-manifest

I have a cache manifest with a specified fallback page that I have set up in an ASP.NET site.  Whenever the connection is offline or the server is unreachable, it shows this page.

This all works beautifully.

The only thing is, when the server is unreachable, it has to timeout before the fallback page appears.  The timeout can take up to 13 or so seconds to occur depending on the platform.  This leaves the user with an awkward span of time before the fallback page appears.

My question is:  What timeout setting is the cache manifest listening to and can I shorten it/change it.

Thanks!